# How can I change a TextEditor's size and maintain the ability that it can autoresize when user zoom app window?

Tags: macos, swiftui, frame

guys.I'm a new developer of MacOS with SwiftUI.
I need to change the default size of TextEditor, and frame(width:height:)modifier will make the view fixed. frame(minWidth:idealWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxWidth:maxHeight) modifier seems not working.
Here's my sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var input: String = ""
var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $input)
}
```

}

Which will generate a 600 * 400 TextEditor View.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hhQk.png)

All I want is the TextEditor has a initial 500 * 600 frame and it will change size when user zoom the app window.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $input)
            .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 500, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 600, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .scaledToFit()
            .border(.red)
    }
}
```